# Зачем метод reader.Read() в этом коде повторяется семь раз?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Приложение для парсинга стен ВКонтакте
<sub>GitHub [ParserWallsVK](https://github.com/AntonZelinsky/ParserWallsVK)</sub>

Не могу понять, зачем `reader.Read()` семь раз повторяется?

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(line));
reader.Read();
reader.Read();

if(reader.Value.ToString() == "error") {
    MessageBox.Show(" С данным идентификатором " +
    (groupRadioButton.Checked ? "группа" : "пользователь") + " не существует.");
    return 0;
}

reader.Read();
reader.Read();
reader.Read();
reader.Read();
reader.Read();

count = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
```

<sub>Отсюда: [Form1.cs](https://github.com/AntonZelinsky/ParserWallsVK/blob/master/Form1.cs)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `Read()` читает следующий JSON-токен. Очевидно, что таким образом автор пропускает ненужные (не имеющие смысла в контексте текущей задачи).

Comment: ... и при этом полагается на их точный порядок, что неправильно и нивелирует положительный эффект от использования парсера.

Comment: а где почитать об этом? и как было бы правильнее сделать?

Comment: @pontekorvo О чем почитать? Про Json.NET (на который опирается вк-парсер) - у него неплохая [документация](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm). Чтобы понять, как работает библиотека, советую попытаться собрать ее из исходников и подебажить. Поставьте там где-нибудь брейкпоинт и посмотрите, какие токены именно пропускаются и почему.

Comment: @pontekorvo автору вк-парсера следовало бы опираться на имена нодов в JSON-структуре, а не пропускать их вслепую, т.к., как правильно тут уже подметили, от перестановки полей данных эта логика пострадает. Но это замечание имеет смысль лишь в случае, если ВК **не** декларирует точный состав и порядок данных.